# javascript $(this).find and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += " hello two";
```

That works for me. But only for the first 'test' division on my page.
I want to add the innerHTML inside where I want it.

so I have a button and when I click it something like this must happen:

```
$this.find("#test").innerHTML += " hello two";
```

But this second code won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery has [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method. You don't need `.find()` for ID selector, use `$('#test').append(' hello two')`

Comment: Use append() method to by pointing #test ID
$('#test').append('hello two');

Comment: IDs must be unique!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't return the element, but the [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) (which doesn't have an `innerHTML` property). If you're using jQuery, a better method would be to rely on [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("#test").append(" hello two");
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fsty9b8a/) is a JSFiddle which demonstrates the `.append()` solution, as well as doing a `console.log()` of your `find()` code so you can open it in your browser's developer console and examine the object for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery selections return jQuery objects, not DOM elements

Using jQuery's [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method allows you to retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object, which allows you to use DOM properties like [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

But jQuery offers its own methods (such as [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)) for modifying the text value of an element. Let's look at some examples:

```js
$(function () {
  
  // Following the OP's pattern of using `.find()`...
  // you have to use `.get()` to retrieve the DOM element from the jQuery Object.
  $(document).find('#test').get(0).innerHTML += ' hello two';
  
  // Or simply use the jQuery selector to directly select the target element.
  // You may also just use square bracket notation to retrieve the DOM element.
  $('#test')[0].innerHTML += ' hello three';
  
  // jQuery's `.text()` method may also be used to get & set the text:
  // Inefficiently, as seen here.
  $('#test').text($('#test').text() + ' hello four');
  
  // Or with a function that returns a new string value to set.
  $('#test').text(function (i, str) { return str + ' hello five' });
  
  // Or with fancy pants ES6 arrow function notation.
  $('#test').text((i, str) => str + ' hello six');
  
  // But using jQuery's `.append()` method is best for this scenario.
  $('#test').append(' hello seven');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">Hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this.find("#test").innerHTML += " hello two";` should be `$(this).find("#test").append(" hello two");` if ever need to use that. .innerHTML is not a jquery method

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("the place you want").append($("#test").text());
});
```

This `$("the place you want")` can be a `tagname` e.g `$("p")` or `id` e.g `$("#first_p")` or `name` e.g `$("[name='name_of_p']")` attribute of the element

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("p").append(" hello two");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<p>Good morning,</p>
```

Comment: Many people prepend variables with $ so other developers know they are jQuery objects. And innerHTML is not a jQuery method so even if they made this change it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes you are right, didnt make the statement right, i have corrected that and thanks anyway